# If I include the unicode "eject" symbol in my web app UI, what are the compatibility risks?

Tags: unicode

In short, how advanced is unicode support in browsers and operating systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode support is, in general, rather widespread. The main problem here is probably that most fonts don’t contain the EJECT SYMBOL character. According to the [font support page at fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23cf/fontsupport.htm), the character exists only in a small set of fonts, none of which is probably shipped with an operating system or other commonly used software. So the user would need find, download, and install a font that contains the character, unless you use font embedding.